# Is there a way to duplicate a particle system onto a seperate mesh without using python?

Tags: mesh, particles

I have two identical meshes for an animal character model. On one of them I've done a bunch of grooming work on the fur that I'd like to now duplicate it to transfer to the other. I'm using 2.92.

I've tried looking up the answer but all of the ones I've found are either from years ago using a version of blender that hardly resembles 2.9, or lay out a bunch of python code that seems to be more trouble than it's worth.

Just wondering if there's either an easy way or alternatively a clever way to do it, or if I'm all out of luck. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the meshes are stacked in the same space:

First, copy the particle-related vertex groups to the other mesh.

Then, disconnect the particle system.

Select the new mesh, then select the one with groom.

Use copy to selected.

Reconnect the hair on the new mesh.

Should be all good. You may have to re-assign the vertex groups in the particle settings.

Best of luck :)

[image]
[image]
[image]